# MS SQL Json array processing with separate arrays

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a problem with JSON data and how to get it in SQL table so the data is:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1121131",
      "idGroups":[
         "123",
         "X999"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Neutral",
         "Service"
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2233154",
      "idGroups":[
         "654321"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Position"
      ]
   }
]
```

and the desired output is

| Id | idGroups | idGroupNames |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1121131 | 123 | Neutral |
| 1121131 | X999 | Service |
| 2233154 | 654321 | Position |

I have trying to get the desired result with `OPENJSON()` and `CROSS APPLY`,  but I think that I'm not getting anywhere.

my original attempt was

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
   {
      "id":"1121131",
      "idGroups":[
         "123",
         "X999"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Neutral",
         "Service"
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2233154",
      "idGroups":[
         "654321"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Position"
      ]
   }
]'
SELECT id,idGroup,idGroupName FROM OPENJSON (@json)
WITH (
    id INT 'strict $.id',
    idGroups NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.idGroups' AS JSON,
    idGroupNames NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.idGroupNames' AS JSON
    ) CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(idGroups)
    WITH (
        idGroup VARCHAR(500) '$'
    ) CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(idGroupNames)
    WITH (
        idGroupName VARCHAR(500) '$'
    )
```

Comment: Please, post your current attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema and two additional `APPLY` operators. The following statement is a possible solution to your problem:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
   {
      "id":"1121131",
      "idGroups":[
         "123",
         "X999"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Neutral",
         "Service"
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2233154",
      "idGroups":[
         "654321"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Position"
      ]
   }
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.id, j1.[value] AS idGroups, j2.[value] AS idGroupNames
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   id nvarchar(7) '$.id',
   idGroups nvarchar(max) '$.idGroups' AS JSON,
   idGroupNames nvarchar(max) '$.idGroupNames' AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.idGroups) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.idGroupNames) j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Comment: That CROSS APPLY with WHERE clause did the trick, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a third `OPENJSON`, using `JSON_VALUE` and a dynamic path.

This only works in SQL Server 2017+

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
   {
      "id":"1121131",
      "idGroups":[
         "123",
         "X999"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Neutral",
         "Service"
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2233154",
      "idGroups":[
         "654321"
      ],
      "idGroupNames":[
         "Position"
      ]
   }
]';

SELECT j.id, j1.[value] AS idGroups, JSON_VALUE(j.idGroupNames, '$[' + j1.[key] + ']') AS idGroupNames
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   id nvarchar(7) '$.id',
   idGroups nvarchar(max) '$.idGroups' AS JSON,
   idGroupNames nvarchar(max) '$.idGroupNames' AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.idGroups) j1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=063cc4f6a57cb46aa854c66032289673)